# Как добавить класс active к текущей кастомной ссылке на активный элемент в owl carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css

вот пен
codepen.io/cache0/pen/JWMNge

вот код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var owlBen = $(".binefits_slider.owl-carousel");
  owlBen.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $.each($('.owl-item'), function(i) {
      var paginatorsLink = $('.ben_page');
      $(paginatorsLink[i])
        // i - counter
        // Give some styles and set background image for pagination item
        .css({
          'background': 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ') center center no-repeat',
          'background-size': 'cover'
        })
        // set Custom Event for pagination item
        .click(function() {
          owlBen.trigger("to.owl.carousel", i);
        });
    });

  });

  owlBen.owlCarousel({
    // Most important owl features
    items: 1,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
    callbacks: true,
    autoplay: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: Так задумано, что по клику по превью - открываются не те картинки, что в превью? :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/sirnightowl/pen/JoJwrE вот пример, в котором устанавливается `active` для активного превью.

Comment: с локальными файлами таких казусов не было)))

Comment: к сожалению в примере превью устанавливается в точки, которые стандартно идут owl-dots owl-dot, интересует именно с кастомными линками чтоб не городить велосипед с пересчетом всех итемов и отсчета от 0 до активного элемента с применением класса active для соответствующего по счету линку

Comment: насчет разных превьюшек, так это ошибка какая-то с плагином - когда в настройках указывается loop: true то создаются еще дубликаты слайдов с классом 'cloned' и их моя считалка тоже считает, поэтому в превьюхах другой адрес ставится

Comment: спасибо большое за пример - это как раз то, что нужно